# Finding vertices of a maximum clique in polynomial time

Tags: np-complete, clique

Say you were given a black box that solves a clique problem in constant time.

You give the black box an undirected graph G with a bound k and it outputs either "Yes" or "No" that the graph G has a clique with at least k vertices.

How would you use this black box to find the vertices of a maximum clique in polynomial time?

Comment: What have you tried?  What research have you done?  Have you read in textbooks about how to convert between decision problems and search problems?  This is a standard topic; there's little point in us repeating material in textbooks to you.  Next time, I recommend you do more self-study and research before asking, so you can formulate a more informed question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first give it $(G,k)$, and if it says yes, you do the following.  You pick an arbitrary vertex $v$ and call your oracle with $(G-v,k)$.  If the oracle says yes, throw away $v$ and forget about it.  If it says no, then $v$ is in every clique of size at least $k$.  Output $v$ and decrease $k$ by one and lather, rinse, repeat.

Comment: So in the next iteration, you give it $(G-v,k-1)$?